# htaccess redirect with RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, owncloud

I've this redirect to organize:

**oldpage:** `http:// example.com/folder/public.php?service=files&t=7a406ad94e3e5b4f6ed247c6a279570a`

**newpage:** `http:// example.com/folder/public.php?service=files&t=1cb5f1a52ccebfebdb218ecbdb70f9e4`

A the beginning I tryed with normal Redirect command in htaccess but I understood its not working because there is some value after .php in the url string, so I found this code using the ReWriteCond:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^service=files&t=7a406ad94e6e5b4f6ed246c6a279570a(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/public\.php$ http:// example.com/folder/public.php?service=files&t=1cb5f1a52ccebfebdb218ecbdb70f9e4 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But also is not working... What is wrong?

I'm very beginner so sorry if its stupid question.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting any error with the code?

Comment: If I use the oldpage url on the browser (also cleaning cache etc.) nothing happend and there is no redirect to the newpage only a 404 error page.

Comment: Does `/folder/public.php` uri exist?

Comment: Yes. exist and is page part of ownCloud Applications - https://apps.owncloud.com, infact the 404 error page come from the application.

Comment: But also if this page is part of an application the htaccess redirect does not work at the first begging?

Comment: ^up - so any one can help me ???